# MySql error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." after 2931 inserts

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I created executable application in vb.net (visual studio 2010).  The big picture is I am trying to move all my MSSQL data to MySQL.

Environment:
Application on MS Server 2003 R2 - x64 SP2
MSSQL on MS Server 2008 R2 Standard x64 SP1
MySql on Ubunto
Using: Connector/Net for 2.0

Right now if I only do 1000 it works fine and reads from sql server loops 1000 times and for each record calls the inserttable function and insert the record.  The issue comes when I try 5000 records.  At record 2932 (and all entries after) the insert produces the following:
Sql error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 192.168.0.14:3306
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamFromHost(String pipeName, String hostName, UInt32 timeout)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

Any ideas why it happens after 2900 entries?

Connection strings

```
<add name="MSSQLdb" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.13; Initial Catalog=sqlserverdb; User ID = IUSR_sqlserverusername; Password=sqlserverpwd"/>
    <add name="MySQLdb" connectionString="server=192.168.0.14;Port=3306;Uid=dbusername; Pwd=dbpassword;database=dbname; pooling=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Primary function

```
Dim myCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLDBConn)
                Dim sSQL As String = 'SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM mssqlservertable'
                Dim myCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSQL, myCon)

                Dim iRetVal As Integer = 0

                Try
                    If myCon.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                        myCon.Open()
                    End If

                    Dim drOrder As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

                    If drOrder.HasRows Then
                        Dim sOutput As String = ""
                        Do While drOrder.Read()
                            Dim sRetVal As String = ""
                            sRetVal = InsertTable(drOrder("ID"), _
                                                        drOrder("ID2"), _
                                                        drOrder("Resume"), _
                                                        drOrder("DateCreated"), _
                                                        drOrder("DateModified"))

                            If sRetVal.StartsWith("ERROR") = True Then
                                LogIt("ID: " & drOrder("ID") & " iCnt: " & iCnt & " Error: " & sRetVal)
                                ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Error found."
                            End If

                            iCnt += 1
                            If iCnt Mod 100000 = 0 Then
                                ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Current count: " & iCnt
                                Application.DoEvents()
                            End If
                        Loop

                        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Final count: " & iCnt
                    Else
                        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "No rows"
                    End If

                Catch sqlEx As MySqlException
                    MessageBox.Show("Sql error: " & sqlEx.ToString)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Regular error: " & ex.ToString)
                Finally
                    myCon.Close()
                    myCon.Dispose()
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Insert function

```
Function InsertTable(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal ID2 As Integer, _
                                         ByVal Resume As String, ByVal DateCreated As DateTime, _
                                         ByVal DateModified As DateTime) As String
        Dim sRetVal As String = ""
        Dim myCon As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(MySQLDBConn)
        Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO mysqltable (ID, ID2, Resume,DateCreated, DateModified)" _
                             & " VALUES (?ID, ?ID2, ?Resume, ?DateCreated, ?DateModified);"
        Dim myCmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sSQL, myCon)
        myCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?ID", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ID
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?ID2", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ID2
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Resume", MySqlDbType.LongText)).Value = Resume
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?DateCreated", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateCreated
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?DateModified", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateModified

        Try
            If myCon.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                myCon.Open()
            End If
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myCmd.Dispose()
        Catch sqlEx As MySqlException
            sRetVal = "ERROR: Sql error: " & sqlEx.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            sRetVal = "ERROR: Regular error: " & ex.ToString
        Finally
            myCon.Close()
            myCon.Dispose()
        End Try

        Return sRetVal
    End Function
```

Comment: Not sure, but, removing that `pooling=false` in the MySql Connection string could be of help. If I understand your code well, you open and close, in a very tight loop, the same connection. It is a perfect use case for connection pooling. Why do you want to do without?

Comment: Thanks Steve - removing the pooling did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are exhausting all of the available ephemeral TCP/IP ports because of the rapid succession of open/close DB connections.  You should open the connection once and use that connection for each of your inserts.  Steve's suggestion of using pooling should also solve this problem for you because the connections will be transparently shared in a similar fashion.